# Web Scraping Text that is missing in the HTML

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to collect some information from a series of forms. The majority of the online forms have the response text coded into the HTML, however, there is one section where this does not seem to be the case. Is there any way to still retrieve the information?

The below link is an example. Specifically, I am looking at the "Source Country" section. The country names like "Italy" and "Spain" do not appear in the HTML. Therefore, I am having trouble getting it with a combination of Selenium and BS4.
https://232app.azurewebsites.net/Forms/ExclusionRequestItem/13700

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data are in the page, but in the form of Javascript array. You can extract it with `re` and `json` module for example:

```
import re
import json
import requests

url = 'https://232app.azurewebsites.net/Forms/ExclusionRequestItem/13700'

html_data = requests.get(url).text

json_data = json.loads(re.findall(r'function createSourceCountriesTable\(\).*?var arrValues = (.*?);', html_data, flags=re.DOTALL)[0])

print(json.dumps(json_data, indent=4))
```

Prints:

```
[
    {
        "OriginCountry": "Spain",
        "ExportCountry": "Italy",
        "ExclusionQty": "20000",
        "Manufacturer": "Rodacciai",
        "Supplier": null
    },
    {
        "OriginCountry": "Spain",
        "ExportCountry": "Spain",
        "ExclusionQty": "3000",
        "Manufacturer": "Aceros Inoxidables Olarra",
        "Supplier": null
    },
    {
        "OriginCountry": "United Kingdom",
        "ExportCountry": "Italy",
        "ExclusionQty": "3000",
        "Manufacturer": "Rodacciai",
        "Supplier": null
    }
]
```